# Display linestring on OsmDroid

Tags: openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using OsmDroid to display some map features on Android. I have a server that displays routes based on a start and a end point. 
The server returns the path/route in a list of points:

> [(Alat,Along),(Blat,Blong),etc...]

What function, of the OsmDroid API should I use to display the route on the map?

Thanks

Comment: Are you mixing up OsmAnd and osmdroid?

Comment: sorry . My mistake - I'm using OsmDroid

Answer (score 0):

You can use osmdroid PathOverlay (even if deprecated).

You can also use [OSMBonusPack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) Polyline.

And, depending on which routing service you are using, you could also have a look at [OSMBonusPack routing features](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Features#Routes_and_Directions).